# How to detect key entered at nth digit

Tags: jquery

I'm trying here to convert Unicode number to normal number. So far I have managed to convert it for 1st digit.
Eg: १ => 1

But when number is 2 digit or more it fail to detect it.

It would be very helpful if anyone could point out how to solve this...

```
var items = ['०', '१', '२', '३', '४', '५', '६', '७', '८', '९'];
$("#xyz").keyup(function(){
    var y = $("#xyz").val();

    if(jQuery.inArray(y, items) !== -1){
        $("#xyz").val(jQuery.inArray(y, items));
    }else{
        console.log('other');
    }

});
```

**Update**

Have managed to convert for nth digit. Only issue is to replace entered string with result. Getting correct output in console but can't replace it in input box

[Jsfiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/jw8krs2h/4/)

```
var items = ['०', '१', '२', '३', '४', '५', '६', '७', '८', '९'];
$("#xyz").keyup(function(){
    var y = $("#xyz").val();
    var res = y.split("");

    var arr = [];
    res.forEach(function(xx) {
        if(jQuery.inArray(xx, items) !== -1){
            arr.push(jQuery.inArray(xx, items));
        }else{
            console.log('other');
        }
    });

    console.log(arr.join(""));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to find a way to type those characters directly into the `input`, so testing was not as thorough as I would want it but, give this a try:

```js
var items = ['०', '१', '२', '३', '४', '५', '६', '७', '८', '९'];
$("#xyz").keyup(function(){
    var y = $("#xyz").val();
    var res = y.split("");
    
    var arr = [];
    res.forEach(function(xx) {
        if(jQuery.inArray(xx, items) !== -1){
            arr.push(jQuery.inArray(xx, items));
        } else if(xx.match(/\d/)){
        arr.push(xx);
        }else{
            console.log('other');
        }
    });

    console.log(arr.join(""));
    $(this).val(arr.join(""));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="xyz"/>
```